# How can I solve a difference-differential equation with new variable?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to ask how we can solve this equation:
$$
xyy' = x^2+2y^2
$$
I tried with new variable $$u=y/x$$

Comment: Are you sure you're on a correct site? Here we answer questions related to Mathematica (a computer system) programming.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica solves the problem easily

```
DSolve[x y[x] y'[x] == x^2 + 2 y[x]^2, y[x], x]

(* {{y[x]->-x Sqrt[-1+x^2 C[1]]},{y[x]->x Sqrt[-1+x^2 C[1]]}} *)
```

From the solutions we conclude that your function u = y/x is simply

```
u[x_] = Sqrt[-1+x^2 C[1]]
```

You can in fact check that this `u[x]` solves the transformed equation

```
x u'[x] = 1/u[x] + u[x]
```

Regards,
Wolfgang